# How to set the filename when downloading a file?

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I'm working on MVC 4. I have generated Excel file dynamically using following simple code. My hosting is on Azure.

I have created a Root path and then try to save that Excel file.

Problem is when my `ActionResult` method response comes back it is giving default popup to open a file but file name is having a GUID instead my provided file name.

Excel file generation code:

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = 
        new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

```
// ...
//Save
        LocalResource resource = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("MyValue");
        string tempPath = resource.RootPath + "DemoFile.xls";
return tempPath;
```

tempPath returns path like `C:\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\11a2435c-998c-4fe8-aa55-8bb42455b4ca\directory\DemoFile.xls`.

The Download File popup does not give file name as `DemoFile` it `gives some GUID` why so?

[image]

`ActionResult` method code:

```
public ActionResult DownloadExcel() {
    string path = ExcelGenerationCode(fileName);
        Stream s = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        return new FileStreamResult(s, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
    }
```

Also tried to give name property

```
public ActionResult DownloadExcel() {
    string path = ExcelGenerationCode(fileName);
        Stream s = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        return new FileStreamResult(s, "application/vnd.ms-excel")
        {
            FileDownloadName = "myexcelFILE1.xls"
        };
    }
```

getting below error when give filename parameter.
[image]

i have plenty of space and memory.

Comment: Show the action method code that lets you download the file.

Comment: ` public ActionResult DownloadExcel()
        {string path = ExcelGenerationCode(fileName);
            Stream s = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            return new FileStreamResult(s, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
        }`

Comment: After your edit, [this is the appropriate duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826649/returning-a-file-to-view-download-in-mvc): you can't set the filename for a `FileStreamResult`, use the [`File(Stream, String, String)` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505200(v=vs.118).aspx). But you don't have to instantiate a stream manually, [`File(String, String, String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492593(v=vs.118).aspx) does the same internally, so you'll have to use less code.

Comment: I updated my answer. Is it working now?

Comment: @CodeCaster thanks but what do you mean "you'll have to use less code"

Please tell me should I use File or FileStreamResult ? and what should be return type ? ActionResult or FileResult ?

Comment: Please try to search for errors. See [How to fix 'Microsoft Excel cannot open or save any more documents'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12415690/how-to-fix-microsoft-excel-cannot-open-or-save-any-more-documents).

Comment: @CodeCaster if I only write 

`string path = DataSetsToExcel(dataSets, planRunName);
Stream s = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
return new FileStreamResult(s, "application/vnd.ms-excel");`

everything working fine but as I mention in my question getting filename as some random GUID (F5CA852C-4F63-4F6D-82A9-45EB9E07FFBE.xls)

and` if I specify the file name using property FileDownloadName` , I'm getting excel memory error :(

Comment: Does that also happen when you kill all Excel instances in your task manager before running this code?

Comment: Ohh I did not realize that THANKS A LOT FRIEND :)
but do you know how do I kill it in my code ? is it necessary to kill in my code ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should return a new FileContentResult and your action must return FileResult instead of ActionResult for ex.:

```
public virtual FileResult DownloadFile(long fileId)
{
     string path = ExcelGenerationCode(fileName);
     return File(path, "application/vnd.ms-excel","donwload.xls");
}
```

Comment: updated my `ActionResult` code in `question above` please check

Comment: _"your action must be a FileResult"_ - not true, `FileResult` inherits `ActionResult`, so the latter will also work.

Comment: working well but getting this error while opening
"microsoft excel cannot open or save any more documents because there is not enough available memory" :/

Comment: problem is i have already pass file name in  path variable then also why it is not taking my file name :/