# IIS Express website works fine, not in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-express

I have an application that uses IIS 7.5X and Visual Studio 2013 and it works fine in IIS Express.  I have had to make changes to allow authentication and allow 32-bit but it still doesn't work on IIS, only IIS express.

I have tried to use the publish in VS2013, but that doesn't seem to work.

Is there anyway I can find the settings used by IIS express so I can set IIS up so it works the same?

Where do I setup logs?  Thanks in advance for not closing this question!

Also, when I run as IISExpress I see the images and styles that don't appear when run as an IIS site.

Where can I find out the settings used by IIS Express?
Pete

Comment: Without more detailed information on actual error messages, server and system logs, it is unlikely you will get any help.

Comment: I have the same problem. Specifically, I am trying to create Word and Excel files using Interop components and on a Windows server 2012 it only works on visual studio and not on the local IIS server

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had to set `Identity` of my application in `Advanced Settings` of `Application Pools` in the IIS to `Custom account` and then set an admin local account to it.
Don't forget to `Restart` your site from the IIS after doing it

Comment: save the day for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. In IIS Express can you make "Deploy -> Export" and than in regular IIS to do "Deploy -> Import" ?

2.
Major settings of IIS stored in files that located in folder C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\