# While downloading excel from Asp.net application its shows the following error

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

While downloading excel from Asp.net application its shows the following error
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Microsoft Excel cannot open or save any more documents because there is not enough available memory or disk space.

• To make more memory available, close workbooks or programs you no longer need.

• To free disk space, delete files you no longer need from the disk you are saving to.

[COMException (0x800a03ec): Microsoft Excel cannot open or save any more documents because there is not enough available memory or disk space.

Comment: Did you try closing some workbooks or deleting some files you no longer need?

Comment: ya cleared all temp files

Comment: it was working fine when we run it in local.if we host the site in IIS.Its show this error.

Comment: Did you you do the same on the server which is hosting the application?

Comment: Sorry cant get you..

Comment: When i am run the code through my local system that means when i run it using visual studio the excel file is downloading..but when it hosted in my system in IIS..when i click that excel download button it shows the above error...

Answer (score 0):

[Original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29273700/4846465)

1.In your application hosting server, go to its "Component Services"

2.Find "Microsoft Excel Application" in right side.

3.Open its properties by right click

4.Under Identity tab select the option interactive user and click Ok button.

---

**Fixing permissions (Windows server 2008)**

**A.Windows 2008 Server x64**

*Please create this folder:*

- C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop

*And give write permissions to the "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool" user in those folders:*

- C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop
- C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft
- C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft

**B.Windows 2008 Server x86**

Please make this folder:

- C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop

*And give write permissions to the "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool" user in those folders:*

- C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop
- C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft
- C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft

Comment: I hosted the website in IIS server.There is not option like Excel Application

Comment: I changed in dcomcnfg bt when i select interactive user.when i click that button it takes me to the login page of my application

Comment: You may want to review the other solutions provided in the Original thread I linked to.

Comment: [COMException (0x800a03ec): Microsoft Excel cannot open or save any more documents because there is not enough available memory or disk space.